# Wrong text color in a page header

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, header-footer

I'm writing a thesis and I've encountered a weird problem. I want the header of each page to show the chapter name. The text must be on the opposite side on even and odd pages due to printing. For all chapters it works great except for the Table of Contents where the header on the left side has the same color as the title rather than the color assigned to it in the preamble. Changing the header color doesn't have any effect but changing the title color also changes the header color.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code to set up the toc and the header:

```
% Table of contents customization
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\bfseries\color{titleBlue}Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\vspace{0.1ex}\endgraf\rule{\linewidth\color{black}}{1.25pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\large}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\large}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\large}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{4pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% Header and footer settings
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{
\normalfont
\color{headGrey}\nouppercase{\textit{\leftmark}}}

\fancyhead[RO]{
\normalfont
\color{headGrey}\nouppercase{\textit{\leftmark}}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{headerBlue!40!white}\hdashrule[0.5ex]{1.\textwidth}{0.75mm}{0.75mm} }
```

[image: Rendering of the example's table of contents]

Comment: How many times do you want to have "Table of Contents" on your page? Readers aren't stupid, a good typographic manner is to have no header on the page with the table of contents.

Comment: It is difficult to say with this example with so many things undefined. Please give a MWE!
But anyway, `\contentsname` will be put in the `\leftmark`, so the blue will go to the header. You would have to get the blue color out of `\contentsname` and get it in the title in another way.

Comment: And, by the way, `\normalfont` is unnecessary, as `fancyhdr` does that already.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the comments. I thought it would keep the coherence of the text to include the header also in toc as it spans multiple pages. I've removed the formatting form `\contentsname` and moved it to `\cfttoctitlefont` and it works as intended.